# Getting com.android.volley.TimeoutError when trying to access PlacesClient.findCurrentPlace()

Tags: android, google-maps, android-volley, google-places

I need to access [PlacesClient.findCurrentPlace()](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/net/PlacesClient#findCurrentPlace(com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindCurrentPlaceRequest)) each time I get a location update through `FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates()`.
I decided to do this by enqueing a `OneTimeWorkRequest` in the `BroadcastReceiver` that is called by the `PendingIntent` passed to `FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates()`:

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        WorkRequest locationRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(HeartBeatWorker.class)
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(locationRequest);
    }
}
```

However, sometimes, the `Worker`'s `doWork` gets the `com.android.volley.TimeoutError` from the `Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse>` returned by the Places SDK call:

```
@Override
public Result doWork() {            
    // Initialize the SDK
    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "<my API key>");

    // Create a new Places client instance
    PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(getApplicationContext());

    // Use fields to define the data types to return.
    List<Place.Field> placeFields = new ArrayList<>();
    placeFields.add(Place.Field.NAME);
    placeFields.add(Place.Field.TYPES);

    // Use the builder to create a FindCurrentPlaceRequest.
    FindCurrentPlaceRequest request = FindCurrentPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeFields);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Call Places SDK to get current PlaceLikelihoods
        Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> placeResponse =
                              placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request);

        placeResponse.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FindCurrentPlaceResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    ...
                } else {
                    // sometimes I fall here, with status code 15.
                    // Looking into it, the error turns out to be:
                    // com.android.volley.TimeoutError
                    Exception exception = task.getException();
                    if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "HeartBeatWorker: Place not found: " + apiException.getStatusCode());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "HeartBeatWorker: No ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission: HeartBeatWorker returning");
    }
    return Result.success();
}
```

I'm aware that Android enacts relevant [power management restrictions](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/power-details) that could cause the network (presumably needed by the Places SDK call) to be unavailable.
However I get the error even when the app is not in Doze mode and it is still in App Standby Bucket = 10 (i.e. [Active](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/appstandby#active-bucket)) and should not have any network restrictions.
What could be the cause of the error, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0#doze_on_the_go):

> A short time after the screen turns off while the device is on
> battery, Doze restricts network access and defers jobs and syncs.

I overlooked this, as it is not explicitly mentioned on the main [Doze guide](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#understand_doze) in the documentation, which still insists that the device should also be stationary to enter Doze:

> If a user leaves a device unplugged and stationary for a period of
> time, with the screen off, the device enters Doze mode.